# Python: How to extract information from an object type

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, binance-api-client

For example, in my case i use this function from Binance API to get information from my account.
In: `client.get_isolated_margin_account()`
Out:

```
{'assets': [{'baseAsset': {'asset': 'BTC',
    'borrowEnabled': True,
    'borrowed': '0',
    'free': '0.00001994',
    'interest': '0',
    'locked': '0',
    'netAsset': '0.00001994',
    'netAssetOfBtc': '0.00001994',
    'repayEnabled': True,
    'totalAsset': '0.00001994'},
   'quoteAsset': {'asset': 'BUSD',
    'borrowEnabled': True,
    'borrowed': '0',
    'free': '73.26136801',
    'interest': '0',
    'locked': '0',
    'netAsset': '73.26136801',
    'netAssetOfBtc': '0.00337369',
    'repayEnabled': True,
    'totalAsset': '73.26136801'},
   'symbol': 'BTCBUSD',
   'isolatedCreated': True,
   'marginLevel': '999',
   'marginLevelStatus': 'EXCESSIVE',
   'marginRatio': '10',
   'indexPrice': '21715.94858571',
   'liquidatePrice': '0',
   'liquidateRate': '0',
   'tradeEnabled': True,
   'enabled': True}],
 'totalAssetOfBtc': '0.00339363',
 'totalLiabilityOfBtc': '0',
 'totalNetAssetOfBtc': '0.00339363'}
```

My question is how do I filter this information, let's say I want to store in a separate variable the 'netAsset'. I don't know how to work with this output

I try to store the info in a data frame:
account = pd.DataFrame(client.get_isolated_margin_account())
account = account.iloc[:,:3]

And then I try to select exactly what I want from it:
account.assets['assets'].netAsset

Comment: The `Out` is probably a `dict`. Look around and find how to work with python dict.

Comment: Please check out some basic python tutorial (e.g. [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)) that explains dictionaries and lists, the two very basic data structures in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp = client.get_isolated_margin_account()['assets'][0]
netAsset_btc = round(float(tmp['baseAsset']['netAsset']), 2)
```

OR

```
netAsset_btc = round(float(client.get_isolated_margin_account()['assets'][0]['baseAsset']['netAsset']), 2)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?